# Galaxy Note 1 - Hangs on start up screen

Tags: data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note

This is the most tragedic thing ever happened to any of my electronic devices...

1. My phone was dead (naturally) battery charge was zero as I was outside waiting for a friend.
2. I wanted to charge it for couple of minutes
3. I went to Samsung Centre
4. The staff showed me a charger cable and asked me to charge there. (point A)
5. Phone was charging
6. Not more than 2 minutes, another staff came and asked me to connect to the negibouring laptop, where it had the charger cable connected (point B)
7. I disconnect from point A and connected to point B. Phone was charging and I started the phone. The was started normally yet battery was very low. (within the first 5 minutes) I shut it down.
8. She came back again and asked me to disconnect from the laptop (point B) as she has another customer who needs to use the laptop
9. So I disconnected from point B and connected back to point A. After 5 more minutes, I saw the charging green bar has increased. So I started the phone. Now phone hanged on the start up screen and keep showing "SAMSUNG"............

Then I asked them why has happened, they said sorry let us recover your phone, your phone has a problem. From the day I bought, I didn't have any issues with my phone and had been using it for year. Phone is up to date and well taken care.

This whole issue has occured due to the fact that Samsung staff asked me to connect my phone to the laptop which automatically upgrades softwares and while upgrading the softwares she disconnected my phone.

They refused to help me by at least giving me back my data. So can someone please help me with proven steps to connect to the kernal and recover my data back?
And I have never connected this phone to a kernal.

I don't know how possible that is either.
[I saw this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1951159). But I have zero understanding what he is talking about ODIN, DOWNLOAD MODE...However if someone can guide me with the steps, I can manage it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with my Galaxy Note 1, this happens mostly because of the reasons such as, Software Bugs, Software Manipulation, Stuck After An Update, Malfunctioning Apps or Defective Memory Card.

The Solution for this is pretty easy you just have to Wipe Cache Partition.

Wiping the cache partition of your phone allows you to remove the cache files which may have been corrupted and caused the phone to power off. There is a possibility that the corrupt cache files may not allow your phone to power On. These cache files are temporary in nature and will be created by the phone once again after you wipe out the current cache files. In order to wipe the cache partition, you need to enter the recovery mode by pressing a specific combination of keys. The combination varies from one Android device to another. Here are some examples:

Samsung: Power button, Volume Down button, Home button.

Nexus: Power button, Volume Down and Volume Up

LG: Power button and Volume Down button

HTC: Volume down and Power button.

To wipe the cache partition, follow these steps:

1. Press and hold the Power button, the Volume Down button, and the Home
   button (for Samsung) all at the same time.
2. Once you see the Android icon, release the Power button but continue
   to press and hold the other two buttons till you see the System
   Recover screen.
3. You will see a menu with many options. Use the Volume Down key to
   highlight the option that says ‘Wipe Cache Partition’.
4. Select the option by using the Power key and the process of wiping
   out the cache partition will initiate.

Once it completes, your phone will automatically reboot and new cache files will be built by your phone. If you are able to go through the entire process successfully and your phone switches on, Voila!! your problem is fixed, but if your Samsung Galaxy won’t turn on or charge even after wiping the cache partition then you must consider resetting the phone to factory settings.

Do let me know happens, after trying my suggested fix.

Answer (score 0):

Download mode: <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd> + <kbd>Power button</kbd>, then <kbd>Volume up</kbd>

It allegedly moves it to download mode so that you can download ODIN

I am in the same boat since yesterday and only saw the recommendation, now going to try.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen and took it to be fixed.  The guy changed a chip on the motherboard.  Said the fix was hitand miss.  It worked. All the data and apps are gone though.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Soft Reset

Start with a soft reset. A soft reset can sometimes resolve minor software issues and should be the first step to take when troubleshooting an Android smartphone.

Power Cycle

Chances are you have already performed a soft reset by attempting to power your phone off and on or by merely restarting your cell phone. If you have not already tried this then go ahead and do so. The solution might be as simple as rebooting your smartphone.

Battery Remove

If possible try removing the battery from your cell phone for 10-15 seconds then reinsert the battery put your phone back together and then see if it will power on properly. If the phone powers on correctly then enjoy your working smartphone.